How can we read nifi multiple flow files into groovy script
I have two flow flies and i want to read those two flow files in to groovy script and i am using the below line in my groovy to read the flow file content, but how do i know which flow file i am reading here, actually i want to compare two flow file content line by line in groovy and if the content is different then only i need to send the different content into output flow file from groovy script, Thank you.
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

how do know from the above which flow file i am reading out of my two incoming flow files.

In groovy processor this code session.get() returns first function from inbound queue.
The order (priority) of files in queue defined by it's properties:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#settings
To read first 2 files from queue you can use an int parameter in session get:
def flowFileList = session.get(2)
if(!flowFileList) return
if(flowFileList.size()<2) {
    session.rollback() // return files back
    return
}
...

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/latest/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html#get(int)

Thank you @daggett, one quick doubt, i need to read the two flow files and compare the data based on the first column,if any difference between the data then i need to add it to the output flow file for the success, below is the code i am using but getting some error.
If(fowFileList.size() >= 2)
def fowFile1 =fowFileList.gt(0)
def  fowFile2 =fowFileList.gt(1)
but getting error here: The Flow file was not created in this session and was not transferred to any Relationship via Processsession.transfer()

so, every file you got from session must be transferred somewhere or dropped. the code snipped you represented is not calling "transfer" method.

Actually i will be getting exactly two flow files into my groovy scripts now i need to read those two flies and need to compare the content line by line,if i found any line has the diffence in the data(either key or value) then i have to add that key and value to the output flow file, so finally my output flow file should contain the delta from the two input flow file, could you please help with some logic on groovy to achieve this please

you can ask another question - "how to compare two files in groovy" or just search over the internet. don't mix 2 different issues/questions. try to solve issues step by step.
